# JavaScript Ajax Call async:false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this AJAX call that receives data from the server. The only solution I've found is to make `async: false` to get the data outside the function. But it is deprecated. Is there any better option to get the variable out the function? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
 var suggest =[];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: //LINK,
        async: false,
        data: {
            "dataA": string
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            suggest = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });
```

I am using the variable i'm getting from the call many times is there any better way to do it?

```
    for (var i = suggest.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 

        for (var j = 0; j < arrString.length; j++) {
            if (suggest[i] === arrString[j]) {
                suggest.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    var obj = {};

    var suggestKey = "Suggesting";
    var suggestArray = [];
        obj[suggestKey] = suggest;
        suggestArray.push(obj);
```

Comment: use asynchronous techniques ... callbacks, promises, async/await

Comment: @JaromandaX would that help me get the same result as using async:false? im looking too just use success data outside the function.

Comment: Asynchronous code reference will help. It's what your question is a duplicate of apparently